How can i read the environment varibles from app center into flutter when build apk in app center?
I want to read
environment variables from app center into flutter
Like add key such as base_url
And value www.example.com
So this key and value i want to use it in flutter when build apk from app center
I try to use pacakge like appcenter
But it doesnt support null saftey

use this bro: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv

@Nguyenfamily i think this can read from only local variables  not from app center
